# WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express, websocket

## Problem Context

I have an express server serving my webpage with HTTPS via the following code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");

const sslKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/certs/key.pem");
const sslCert = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/certs/cert.pem");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/pages/index.html");
});

https
  .createServer(
    {
      key: sslKey,
      cert: sslCert,
    },
    app
  )
  .listen(3000);
```

The webpage is connecting to a Python websocket server running on my computer on port 8080 via the following code:

```
const server = "127.0.0.1";
const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://${server}:8080`);
```

And my Python websocket server is running based on the following code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import random
import string
import subprocess
import os
import logging
import ssl
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

logging.basicConfig()

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)

ssl_cert = "certs/cert.pem"
ssl_key = "certs/key.pem"

ssl_context.load_cert_chain(ssl_cert, keyfile=ssl_key)

async def server(websocket, path):
    await call_some_custom_irrelevant_function_with_the_socket(websocket, path)


start_server = websockets.serve(
    server, "127.0.0.1", 8080, ssl=ssl_context, origins="*")


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

There are separate TLS/SSL certificates being used by both, the express server, and the Python websocket server. I generated them and granted them trust on my local computer using [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert), a way to generate and automatically grant certificates trusted authority on your local device. Certificates for both are placed inside the `certs` directory of each's project folder and appropriately referenced in the code.

The command I used to generate certificates for both was:

```
mkcert localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

I run the Python websocket server with `python app.py` in its directory successfully, and start my express app using `nodemon app.js` in its directory as well, being able to access `https://localhost:3000` in a secure manner.

## Problem

When I open my webpage and pull the trigger to connect to the websocket server (Irrelevant code as it's just an event handler on a button that calls the websocket connection code I gave above and some other irrelevant socket event stuff), it waits for like 1 second and then gives out the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed:
```

I researched a bit regarding this and it *seems* that there may be some sort of problem with how I am integrating my TLS/SSL certificates, however, I am clueless as to exactly what. If someone could help me out in fixing this, or even point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Comment I thought not worth including in the question: Please ignore the speech_recognition imports as those have nothing to do with the problem itself, that is more of what I will be utilizing these websockets for later on. At the moment, they are just unused imports that happened to get carried into my code, not sure if editing them out would be appropriate in accordance with StackOverflow.